# Markerless AR for android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

Is there any Augmented Reality Framework which support marketless tracking on android phone ?
i have searched a lot but mostly are marker based framework

Framework that does not support Marker less Detection

Qualcomm ( QCAR ) 
ARToolkit
NyARToolKit

someone has suggested Ferns but no idea how well that product is for android phones

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any to my knowledge. There are some videos floating around that demonstrate a PTAM implementation on Android phones from a korean university, but it hasn't been released yet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no framework for sensor based (using GPS, accelerometer, magnetometer) AR yet. The framework exist only support marker-based augmented reality.

But you can use [Wikitude API](http://www.wikitude.com/category/04_developer/wikitude-api) or create it from scrath.
There is an example of sensor based augmented reality [here](http://nhenze.net/?p=561). You can try to learn from it and you can also download the code example.