# Markerless tracking android

Tags: android, opencv, augmented-reality, artoolkit

Three years ago a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136780/markerless-ar-for-android) was asked, but i think that enough time has passed to make the answers obsolete.

The question is simple, is there a way to do **markerless tracking** using [ARToolKit](http://artoolkit.org/) or other **free** libraries in the **android** framework? If there exists a free framework that can do this please, put a reference to the resource.

I have searched a lot, but everything i could find is not given for free, like [Vuforia](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/vuforia).

What i managed to do until now is to build an opencv app that allows the user to take a pic of the chosen marker, and then OpenGL stuff is rendered on top of the tracked marker. Unfortunately the camera intrinsics is required, and on top of that i have problems related to the tracking, which is quite unstable. For this reasons i am searching some other framework such as [ARToolKit](http://artoolkit.org/), but i couldnt find any reference to markerless tracking.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARToolKit is a marker based AR library (and so is vuforia). I think you're mixing concepts and you want to use an image as marker (which is still a marker)

In that case the answer is yes, you can use ARToolKit. They are called NFT -natural feature trackers-.

Comment: Vuforia now claims to support markerless tracking in its latest version. However, I haven't tested it yet. I'm not sure how well it works. I assume it has some higher hardware requirements.

Comment: I may have missed that announcement. Will check out out, thanks.

Comment: I think they call it 3D object tracking. I assume that's what he meant by markerless tracking.

Comment: Thank you shalafi, you were right when u said that i was confused. I re-read the artoolkit documentation finding out [what are and how to use NFT](http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=3_Marker_Training:marker_nft_training).